# sql Search a string between certain words

Tags: sql, plsql

If the key word is "Find", is it possible to extract a string that is between the "Find"?

```
stackoverflow is awesome. FindHello, World!Find It has everything!
```

The result should be 'Hello, World!' because the string is between "Find"
My initial idea was to use Instr to locate two "Find", then locate what's between "Find".

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Your idea is fine.  Use instr() to solve this,.

Comment: How are you going to deal with the case when Find exists 4 times in the string?

Comment: "Find" is just an example. The actual key word will be unique and will happend only twice.

Comment: If twice - the surely instr/substr else regexp_substr + connect_by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either [regular expressions](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html) or [`instr()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) to achieve what you're after.

I actually prefer regular expressions, if you're using version 10g or later, because I find doing multiple contortions with `instr()` fairly unwieldy, but it's up to you.

```
with phrases as (
  select 'stackoverflow is awesome. FindHello, World!Find It has everything!' as phrase
    from dual
         )
select substr( phrase
             , instr(phrase,'Find',1,1) + 4
             , instr(phrase,'Find',1,2) 
                 - instr(phrase,'Find',1,1)
                 - 4
               )
  from phrases
```

This gets the first and second occurrences of the string `Find`, starting from the first character, then uses these to work out the positions that you should be doing the sub-string on.

Alternatively, using regular expressions:

```
with phrases as (
  select 'stackoverflow is awesome. FindHello, World!Find It has everything!' as phrase
    from dual
         )
select regexp_replace(phrase
     , '([[:print:]]+Find)([[:print:]]+)(Find[[:print:]]+)', '\2')
  from phrases
       ;
```

This takes any printable character multiple times, followed by the string `Find` etc. But, the main bit is the grouping `()`, which separates each part of the phrase. The `\2` means that of the original matched string only the second group, i.e. that between the `Find`'s is returned.

Here's a little [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29f41/14) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

This query suppose to handle more than two 'Find's

```
with SourceString as( 
   select 'Find123Find45345Find76876234Find87687Find' s_string
        , 'Find' delimiter 
     from dual
)  

select substr(s_string, f_f - s_f + length(delimiter), s_f-Length(delimiter ) )
  from (select f_f
             , s_f
         from(select f_f
                   , f_f  - lag(f_f, 1, f_f) over(order by 1) s_f 
                from (select Instr(s_string, delimiter , 1, level) f_f
                        from SourceString
                     connect by level <= Length(s_string))
                     )
       where s_f > 0) 
     , SourceString
```